# How to get oldest message id GMAIL API

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm using to get the list of message_ID `users_messages->listusersmessages`. Is there a way to get the oldest message_ID?

Comment: I mean I want to get oldest message time when it was received, anyone could help with it?

Comment: It may not be possible without doing/create a function. Checking [Search operators you can use with Gmail] will give you the allowed advance search supported by Gmail/Gmail API. You might as well get the list of message then get the last id using a function.

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not specify the order in which to list messages, at this time. You will have to [list every message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) until you get the last page of message ids:

**Request 1**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response 1**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "155fd69a74bceff0",
   "threadId": "155fd69a74bceff0"
  }, ...
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "03259718007012574564",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 103
}
```

Use the `nextPageToken`, and continue to list messages until there is no `nextPageToken` in the response.

**Request 2**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?pageToken=03259718007012574564&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response 2**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "155772ef5633f85b",
   "threadId": "155772ef5633f85b"
  },
  ...,
  {
   "id": "1557460c0e3b5a89",
   "threadId": "1557460c0e3b5a89"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 103
}
```

This response has no `nextPageToken`, so `1557460c0e3b5a89` is the last one.

Comment: @user2808421 No problem! Did it answer your question? Consider accepting the answer, if that is the case.