# Python Gmail API. Search for emails based on Labels and Ascending Time Order?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API with Python. I would like to search for email messages using a label, in time ascending order. I am able to search for emails using a label or list of labels with the following function:

```py
def gmailAPIMessageLabelSearch(self, labelList, userID="me", allPages=False):
    try:
        self.GLogger.info("Attempting to search emails with labelList (" + str(labelList)+ ") and userID (" +str(userID)+ ")")
        service = self.gmailAPIService
        if service is None:
            logging.error('Gmail Service not initialized')
            return False
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList).execute()
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])
        if allPages is True:     
            while 'nextPageToken' in response:
                page_token = response['nextPageToken']
                response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, pageToken=page_token).execute()
                if 'messages' in response:
                    messages.extend(response['messages'])
        self.GLogger.info("Successfully searched emails with labelList (" + str(labelList)+ ") and userID (" +str(userID)+ "). Number of matching emails (" +str(len(messages))+ ")")
        return messages
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered while searching for messages with google API and label list")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

However, I would specifically like to ensure that I am receiving emails in Time Ascending Order. So the search should return with the oldest first and newest last.

Also, I am not able to simply download the emails and then sort. The emails are used in real time, so they cannot be stored and then sorted. I am aware it would be possible to simply download the emails and then extract their time and sort accordingly. However, this is not an option. I would need the results of the search to already provide this list in ascending time order.

Is there a way of doing this?

I tried searching and checking the Gmail API for the list() function but I don't see a way. I tried applying "Oldest" label, and didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you verify that the request you are making doesn't return the messages in either ascending or descending order?

Comment: Based on what I have been reading, the messages are returned in descending order. So newest first and oldest last, similar to how you would scroll through messages page-by-page if you were logged in through the Browser Gmail GUI.

Comment: Seems like I can use my function as is, but I will need to fetch all emails with label INBOX and UNREAD. Once I have all of those ids, I will then need to read the list in reverse order and manage the emails that way. This will achieve the requirement of managing the emails in oldest to newest, although it is a less then ideal solution.

Comment: The Post I am referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411142/how-to-get-oldest-message-id-gmail-api. This is also consistent with my observations of how the emails are queried.

Answer (score 1):

As Google mail does not provide the ability to invert the sorting, the easiest way is to retrieve the first page using [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list), the response then includes an estimate for the total number of results `resultSizeEstimate`, based on this you can jump to the last page and then you only have to sort the emails from that page.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs say](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list#query-parameters) the the `q` parameter supports the same query format as the Gmail search box.

See here for which terms it accepts: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en
Some of those terms can be useful to filter messages.